# what is the scope of Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two applications A and B hosted in a same web server. Application A have a folder named `Uploads`. Now !! the code inside my application B need to access the folder `Uploads` in application A. Is it possible through?

for eg:   var path = Server.MapPath("Uploads").ToString();

Comment: Server.MapPath("Uploads"); only gives you the path from the current solution directory to the "Uploads" folder.

Comment: by using Server.MapPath(); you actually referring the directory where you project solution is placed and this method returns you the full path where your current project solution is placed on the disk drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) incorrectly states

> Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server

The path is always from the root of the current web site / web application.

Comment: So you are saying it is not possible. So it is better that I keep it in shared folder

Comment: You can access any folder on the hard drive as long as you have permissions. You could try to use a virtual path `Server.MapPath("..\\Uploads")` or add the upload folder to your web.config and use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"]`